# Can I find out if PCI-e slot is 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0 in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, pci-express, pci, hardware-detection

I'm going to purchase a GPU which is for PCI-e 3.0.
But since I don't know what PCI-e slot it is in my computer I need to find it out somehow.
Is it possible to find it from the terminal in linux?

Comment: Not asked, but nice to know: A PCI-e v3 card will run fine on an PCI-e v2 slot.

Answer (score 42):

Using `lspci -vv` as root, you can get the transfer rate and compare it with the transfer rate [specified for the revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions).  A sample output would read:

```
# lspci -vv | grep -E 'PCI bridge|LnkCap'
00:02.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
                LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <512ns, L1 <4us
00:03.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <512ns, L1 <4us
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <512ns, L1 <4us
00:10.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PCI Bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
```

Which shows that the speed here is 2.5GT/s, corresponding to PCIe 1.x.

Comment: This needs to run as root; without it, `lspci` silently prints `Capabilities: <access denied>`, which is removed by the `grep`.

Comment: That's what the `#` means.

Comment: That shows the CURRENT transfer speed. An idle system will all show the lowest speed it is allowed to run at. You can't use this at all.

Comment: @KenSharp My understanding is that `LnkCap` is the link capability, not the current throughput rate. Do you have a source for your claim?

Answer (score 24):

You can use the  "dmidecode" command to give an in depth list of all the hardware on the system and then view that.    I did a "quick and dirty" command to show the pertinent bit as follows:

```
dmidecode | grep "PCI"
```

Which returned

```
PCI is supported
Type: x16 PCI Express 2 x8
Type: x8 PCI Express 2 x4
Type: x8 PCI Express 2 x4
Type: x8 PCI Express 2 x4
Type: 32-bit PCI
```

Comment: `dmidecode --type 9` can also be used to filter while keeping the rest of the information.

Comment: only shows "Type: x16 PCI Express" for me. So no PCIe version...

Comment: I think this lists the slot native speed but if the BIOS has a slot set to previous generation or an older card is dropping the slot generation I don't think this reflects it.